# A test for a binomial r.v. vs. sum of two binomial r.v.'s?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, mathematical-statistics, binomial-distribution, optimal

Suppose I draw a sample from one of the two possible random variables $X$ or $Y$ where $X\sim\text{Binomial}(p,N)$ and $Y=A+B$ with $A\sim\text{Binomial}(p,M)$ and $B\sim\text{Binomial}(q,N-M)$. Assume unknown $q\geq p$, with $p$, $M$ and $N$ known.  My objective is to distinguish which random variable my sample came from, that is test hypotheses $q=p$ vs. $q> p$.

It seems like a simple threshold test is appropriate, but I can't figure out how to justify it mathematically.  Neyman-Pearson lemma isn't applicable since the alternate hypothesis ($q>p$) is not simple.  Is there an UMP test for this problem?  Some other measure of optimality?  Any suggestions?

Comment: In the cases where you get the same form of test at each point alternative, you'll get a UMP test. I don't know if that applies here though.

Comment: Interesting. I only know of the monotone and non-decreasing condition on the likelihood ratio for UMP, but had trouble proving that (since one of the likelihood functions is a convolution).  What do you mean by the "same form of a test"?  Perhaps you could provide a reference to a relevant lemma?

Comment: I wasn't being precise. There's an example of a slightly more precise version of the argument [here](http://www.stat.tamu.edu/~hart/611/neyman.alt.pdf).

Comment: While there could well be a UMP test here, the existence of UMP tests are not *necessarily* to be expected more generally. Nonetheless, there are various reasons to expect likelihood ratio tests will usually have desirable properties.

Comment: Thanks for a helpful link. My variables are in fact being added (though a convolution can be thought of as a mixture of random variables). I think if I can show that the likelihood ratio is non-decreasing monotonically over the support $1,2,\ldots,N$, then I can claim that LRT is an UMP test (per Lehmann&Romano Ch. 3). However, I am having trouble showing that the likelihood ratio is non-decreasing even though plotting it in Wolfram Mathematica suggests it is. I posted a question about that to math.SE: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/734453/is-this-function-monotonically-non-decreasing

Comment: On the 'addition' - thanks; I eventually figured out that you did in fact mean convolution, which is why I deleted the comment. Sorry for being slow on the uptake there. I think it may be best to avoid doing it explicitly as a convolution if possible, and if you can, to work with the log of the likelihood-ratio. [In the case where M=0, the problem is very simple, but presumably you knew that already]

Comment: I've been thinking about the link that you posted, and I am now pretty convinced that a test that compares the sample value $x$ to some threshold $t$, rejecting null if $x>t$, is UMP. This is because size $\alpha$ of this test doesn't depend on $q$ (and $M$). This also agrees with my plots of the likelihood function in Mathematica (though still I haven't been able to formally prove that it's increasing)...  Thoughts?

Comment: I completely agree with your understanding of the situation, since it's the same as the conclusion I came to (both that the likelihood is monotonic and that the test will be UMP). I don't know that I'd be able to prove it in the amount of time I'd have available to spend on it, though. I expect there's some relatively obvious fact I've overlooked that makes that relatively simple.